# How to use XSLTProcessor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use XSLTProcessor class in my typescript code but i get the error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'XSLTProcessor'.
```

I see that it is defined in `lib.es6.d.ts`. 
In my config i have:

```
 ...
 "module": "commonjs",
 "target": "es6",
 "lib": [
     "es6"
 ],
 ...
```

I'm newbie in JS/TS world but if TS is the superset of JS then why can't I just use sth that is available in JS?

How to make TS to use this class?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = new XSLTProcessor();
```

XSLTProcessor is built-in in the browser, there's no need to import anything.

Comment: Yes, it works in browser console (in clear JS) but not works in TypeScript (See error above.